# Escrever HTML e PHP na mesma linha

Tags: php, html

```
<p> " <?=$testemunhos[$i]['testemunho']?> " <p>
```

Eu quero escrever na mesma linha, mas esta ficando assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e eu queria assim

" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sed magna aliquet, congue nunc at, lacinia neque. "

alguma dica?

```
<? $testemunhos=$testemunhos->getTestemunhos();  ?>


                            <ul class="rslides" id="comentarios">
                                <? for($i=0;$i<count($testemunhos);$i++){ ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="avaliacao">
                                             <p> " <?=($testemunhos[$i]['testemunho']) ?> " <p>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <? } ?>     
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Você precisa especificar um tamanho para o container do seu conteúdo, assim quando o texto for maior que o tamanho do seu container, ele vai jogar o conteúdo para baixo.

Comment: Dá um CTRL+U e olhe no código-fonte o que mostra o HTML. Me parece que o código PHP está retornando  outro parágrafo.

Comment: sim, esta retornardo 3 paragrafos, 2 para as " e 1 para o texto

Comment: Tente remover os parágrafos com o `str_replace`.

Comment: Olhe no código-fonte do navegador e veja o que mostra o HTML.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ciOOMI8

Comment: Vc está abrindo dois `<p>`... o último tinha que ser `</p>`.

Comment: sim, tem razao tinha um erro no codigo, ja resolvi mas o problema continua

Comment: descobri o problema, mas continuo sem saber como posso resolver. eu estou a usar o CKEDITOR e ele vai guardar na Base de Dados como paragrafo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que o texto retornado em `<?=$testemunhos[$i]['testemunho']?>` está vindo com um parágrafo, algo assim:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Ut sed magna aliquet, congue nunc at, lacinia neque.</p>
```

Com isso, o navegador irá fechar o `<p>` que já está no HTML, porque não se pode aninhar um parágrafo dentro do outro, e está ficando assim:

```
<p> " </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
"
<p></p>
```

Outra coisa é que você não fechou o `<p>` do HTML, você abriu ele duas vezes:

```
<p> " <?=($testemunhos[$i]['testemunho']) ?> " <p>
 ↑                                              ↑
```

O correto seria:

```
<p> " <?=($testemunhos[$i]['testemunho']) ?> " </p>
 ↑                                              ↑
 abrindo                                     fechando
```

Mas mesmo corrigindo o segundo `<p>` para `</p>`, ainda vai dar problema com o `<p>` vindo do PHP, como falei no início.

O que pode ser feito, é eliminar as tags `<p>` do PHP usando `preg_replace`:

```
<p> " <?=preg_replace('/<\/?p>/', '', $testemunhos[$i]['testemunho'])?> " </p>
```

Comment: obrigado, era mesmo isso que estava a procura

Comment: De nada. Mas o ideal mesmo era eliminar as tags <p> quando fosse salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: Se já tem `<p>` no banco de dados, pode simplesmente não colocar outros `<p>` por fora

Comment: @bfavaretto Pensei nisso tb, mas é que as aspas tem que ficar dentro do <p>.

Comment: É verdade... ...

Comment: A regex pode ser apenas `/<\/?p>/` (a barra é opcional, então já abrange a abertura e fechamento da tag)

Comment: @hkotsubo Isso mesmo, valeu! Sabia que tinha alguma coisa nessa regex a melhorar rs